# How to set all controls with in my form Size in vb.net 2010?

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0

I am working on a project, and it needs to create some specific no. of buttons in runtime. Program is going well but all buttons are creating outside of the form size. How to resolve this? (all buttons will be placed within my form size, nothing will be out of this) Help me soon.

Comment: you should include what you've tried so far.

Comment: Put the buttons inside a FlowLayoutPanel.  If you need more help, document  your question better.

Comment: thanks flowlayout panel is working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For square buttons:
assuming 0 padding and that you want to completely fill the area with an even number of square buttons.

```
fill area width * Fill Area height = fill area
fill area / number of buttons = button sizeX = button sizeY
```

But I like the answer provided by LarsTech.

Let me know if this helps you at all.